# How to stop auto scrolling in nested scroll view if i use search bar?

Tags: flutter

I'm scrolled the list and in the middle if i clicked on the search bar then the list will auto scrolling to index '0'

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 255, 144),
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  primary: true,
                  floating: true,
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 255, 144),
                  snap: true,
                  pinned: false,
                  bottom: PreferredSize(
                    preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(48),
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 218, 255, 144),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 15, bottom: 14, right: 15, top: 15),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              cursorColor: Colors.black,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  fillColor:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(30, 50, 50, 122),
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                                  hintText: 'Search',
                                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(
                                        153,
                                        60,
                                        60,
                                        67,
                                      ),
                                      fontSize: 17,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  filled: true,
                                  prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.search,
                                    color: Color.fromARGB(
                                      153,
                                      60,
                                      60,
                                      67,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  suffixIcon: MaterialButton(
                                      minWidth: 10,
                                      splashColor: Colors.grey,
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      child: const Icon(
                                        Icons.clear,
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(
                                          153,
                                          60,
                                          60,
                                          67,
                                        ),
                                      ))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: const MyScreen(),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 48,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
              elevation: 0,
              title: const Text("My Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(223, 0, 0, 0)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_rounded,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(223, 0, 0, 0)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
        itemCount: 1000,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(index.toString()),
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider());
  }
}
```

I tried to stop the auto scrolling when i click on the search bar, so please help me out to stop the auto scroll to start and remove the gap after that app bar and list, please beautify the code ,sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Just add this line to your NestedScrollView

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

[image]

Comment: thank you bro, its working.
and can you suggest me how to remove that gap between the list and app bar.

Comment: Add this line ```padding: EdgeInsets.zero,``` inside ListView.separated()